# iOS - setKeepAliveTimeout handler causing semaphore_wait_trap

Tags: ios, objective-c, handler, sip, background-process

right now I'm trying to develop SIP phone application in iOS and I'm using setKeepAliveTimeout to keep the connection connected when the application goes to background, I set the timeout time to 600 seconds (Apple minimum standart) but after 600 seconds the app will be stopped and all I see is semaphore_wait_trap on main thread. Did anyone have idea about this?

I also tried to NSLog inside the handler but the log isn't called so I assume the handler is not running. I hope my question is clear enough, but if you need more information about my question please leave a comment.

Thank you